# java XML dtd, sax parser

Tags: java, parsing, tags, sax, dtd

I've an xml document that has the following

```
<!DOCTYPE TRACE PUBLIC "trace.dtd" "trace.dtd">
```

after the first line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

When I parse it using SAX xml parser, I get the following error...

```
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\<BLAH>\trace.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Any ideas how to bypass this tag in order to parse the xml successfully?

Comment: The msg si clear : java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\<BLAH>\trace.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified). You specified bad path value. It didn't find the file you want to parse

Comment: nope, sir, when i remove that tag from the file, it reads the file ;) so the problem is with that tag. Thanks for answering

Comment: I agree with @David.BC. It is a clear error message. If you want to validate your assumption run the code on two different files, one with the tag and one without (Do not edit `trace.dtd` but make an edited copy of it)

Comment: Same thing, i just checked. It's due to trace.dtd tag at the beginning. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well 
according to this

[SAXParser throws FileNotFoundException despite not being given a file to parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375123/saxparser-throws-filenotfoundexception-despite-not-being-given-a-file-to-parse)

it worked just fine

```
factory.setValidating(false);
factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
```